# Sql server-client installment

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssh

i don't know where to ask this I hope sof is the right place.

I give t-sql classes to a professional school, and it's my first time. The school doesn't have any software installed but they want it to be microsoft sql server only. So the thing is, I know in oracle I can have a server installed at home and my students use a client to connect to it and each using their separete db-user, execute the tasks I ask, all is fine and dandy. With sql server from microsoft I don't even know/can't find a client version... I'm talking about 2012 version. 
So... is there a client software to acess a sql server or any other similar way? Currently I enabled everything I could related to ssh and I'm trying to connect with other machine to my sql server via ssh but to no success. (I considered this another possible solution)

The thing is, I don't wan't to install 20 SQL servers on desktops... I think it doesn't make much sense since all their tasks are related to SQL sintaxe and basic rules and database normalization.

I'm sorry for my english, I'm not native.

Comment: SSMS can be downloaded and installed without SQl Server, if you're looking for something like that. Than you just need to setup a connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sqlserver Manament Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593). Which is used to connect sqlserver from client or server means, in network or even though from live sqlserver too.

one thing you remember about 32-bit , 64 bit version.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb934498.aspx

Follow the link that how to install SSMS.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx